# Inserting JSON into Oracle table with python

Tags: python, json, oracle

What I need to do is to use a json file and load each json object as a registry in the table,
I managed to do it with python and postgresql using the psycopg2 library, but now I need to accomplish this with Oracle.

I've been looking for this and so far what I have found is that you can insert the json but as a CLOB registry and not each json object as a unique registry.

The json would look like this:

```
[
 {
  "product_id": "ABC123", 
  "product_name": "Towel", 
  "product_description": "White", 
 }, 
 {
  "product_id": "DEF456", 
  "product_name": "Towel", 
  "product_description": "Green",
 }, 
 {
  "product_id": "FS1C9", 
  "product_name": "Shoes", 
  "product_description": "Brown"     
 }
]
```

And the table would be like this:

```
Table Product
 product_id varchar(12),
 product_name varchar(12),
 product_description varchar(25)
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I have been struggling with this for a while.

This is the piece of code that I use to upload the JSON with psycopg2:

```
db_config = {dbcredentials}
conn = psycopg2.connect(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor()
extras.execute_batch(cursor, query, jsonObjectList, page_size=1000)
```

where the jsonObjectList is the json that I showed before and the query would be

```
"INSERT INTO product("product_id", "product_name", 
"product_description") VALUES (%(PRODUCT_ID)s, %(PRODUCT_NAME)s, %
(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION)s)"
```

And that's all I need to upload a json with python and psycopg2.

Comment: Show your code and the errors you got.

Comment: There's no code since I haven't found the documentation for what I need to accomplish. Anyway, I found another way. Parse the json into a csv style and then upload it with the `cursor.executemany` instruction.

Comment: if you post your psycopg2 code it would help. The naive solution for either database would be `json.loads` and then `cursor.executemany`. I am not sure why you would need "csv" format just for oracle.

Comment: my bad, I added the code that I use with psycopg2

Comment: Google didn't help me understand what you meant by 'registry'.  You may need to decompose your JSON and use cursor.executemany() as suggested by @john-bright or write a PL/SQL function to decompose your JSON into relational values once it hits the DB.  But if you have Oracle Database 12.2, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/toc.htm and make use of the extensive native JSON functionality.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I'm going to do. Decompose the JSON and use cursor.executemany().